# Storing white chocolate

Tags: chocolate, decorating

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long can you keep chocolate, and what is the best way to store it?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11248/how-long-can-you-keep-chocolate-and-what-is-the-best-way-to-store-it)

I just started using white chocolate to decorate dark chocolate covered cake balls. I used a squeeze bottle instead of the standard bag and it worked beautifully. I need to store the left over white chocolate though. What is the best way and how long will it keep? Thanks!

Comment: welcome to this site.  You might find the answer in this question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11248/how-long-can-you-keep-chocolate-and-what-is-the-best-way-to-store-it
(except yours is kept in a squirt bottle, of course)

Comment: Just don't keep it *in* the squeeze bottle, or you'll have an interesting time trying to get it back out of there... anyway, the dupe does address white chocolate (it's the same as any other chocolate, just won't last quite as long). Also, [stilltasty](http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/16868) is a good resource for getting broad estimates of the storage lifetime.